# Revert/Reset/Rebase commit after numerous merge and revert merge?

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase, revert

I need to reset or rebase or whatever. My problem is :
I have a git repo and I have been committing and merge branches for 1 week. However, I would really like to delete all the bad commits without history. (I work alone on this repo).

Example, we are on ***'dev'*** :

> today - e8574d7 - Merged 'US#844 - add community card'

> yesterday - 2623efe7 - Merge branch 'revert-798ce959' into 'dev'

> 2 days ago - 5859574c - display vote on cards

> 3 days ago - g578595g - Revert merge...

> Multiple merges & revert...

> 7 days ago - 11111aa - Application v.1.1.2

I want to delete all these commits until I get a "clean" branch starting from commit "11111aa" Application v1.1.2

I tried git reverse HEAD~17..HEAD or git reverse 11111aa but there are always an error.
Thus, i tried to create a new branch from the cleaner commit, but now when i want to merge, it's a disaster.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you wish to throwaway some commits (remove them completely from the history), so you want `reset`.

If you wish to throwaway everything that happened after commit `11111aa`  as if it never happened, then you can simply use a *hard reset*:

```
git switch dev # in case you don't already have it checked out
git reset --hard 11111aa
```

If you like the state of some of the *code* on `dev`, and just want to completely redo the commits, you could do a *mixed reset*, and mixed is the default so you don't need to specify `--mixed` in this case:

```
git switch dev # in case you don't already have it checked out
git reset 11111aa
```

With a mixed reset your branch will be pointing to commit `11111aa` and all the changes you made after that will now appear as pending changes, and you can re-stage and re-commit whatever you'd like in one or more "good" commits.

I'm fairly certain you want to use a hard reset based on the description of your question, but if there's even one file change you like that happened after `11111aa`, a mixed reset will be slightly faster so you can re-commit that one change and undo all the remaining files. And if you like an entire commit, for example, if you want to keep commit `5859574c`, you could use a hard reset and then cherry-pick the commit(s) you like:

```
git switch dev # in case you don't already have it checked out
git reset --hard 11111aa
git cherry-pick 5859574c
```

Note you can accomplish the hard reset and cherry-pick combination using an interactive rebase too, which may be why your research brought up the term rebase to begin with.